# Multiple custom checkbox component designes in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, checkbox, components

Is it possible to create multiple custom checkbox component designes in flash?

I have drag & dropped a checkBox component from components panel and customized it.
Now when I drag another checkBox component from components panel, it asks me whether I want to use existing component or replace existing component.
I need a new, different one.

Use case: I want to use checkBox for turning on/off sound and full-screen in a flash game.
Both checkBoxes have different design.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 way of doing that :
- create a programmatic checkbox item (classes & code have the same behavior as the checkbox component), > it seems that its not the solution you're looking for and requires a little (if not more) knowledge of Actionscript
- or duplicate the existing checkbox component that stands in your library.

This second solution is quicker, and involves having multiples copies of the Checkbox component into your library.
Having multiple times the same component is possible, but they must not share the same name if they're in the same library folder.
To go on that method, you can either :
- in your FLA file, create a new library folder, put everything related to the checkbox in it, then drag again the checkbox from the component panel into your library, and customize the second one.
- in a new FLA file, drag the checkbox component into your library, rename each and every movieclip that was created in the process (adding "_2" at the end of all the names for example) and copy all symbols into your main file library
- or duplicate all checkbox related movieclips (in the library, right click on the symbols > duplicate, in the newly opened window, change the name) and then replace the movieclips in the second checkbox by the duplicated ones, then customize them.

Hopes its clear enough for you to understand, feel free to ask more details if you need to !

Answer (score 0):

Just change the style of an instance at runtime using the `checkbox.setStyle("propertyName",value)` method;

You can find a list of available style properties here (basically the various states of the button):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/CheckBox.html#styleSummary

HOW TO DO IT:
In the flash library, find the checkbox skin assets.  (usually in a folder called Component Assets/CheckBoxSkins. Right click 'CheckBox_upIcon' and select duplicate. Give a a relevant name, then check "export for actionscript" , give it a class name, lets say "FullScreenCheckbox_upIcon".

Now in your code you can tell any checkbox to use that skin. If your full screen checkbox had an instance name of fCheckBox, you could do this:

```
fCheckBox.setStyle("icon",FullScreenCheckBox_upIcon);
```

Repeat the step for any of the other states (down, over) you want different.